# Loop on comments on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping

I was wondering if there is any option to loop on comments of a certain post?

for example I'm trying to loop on the comments for a post that looks like

```
https://www.facebook.com/{publisher_name}/posts/{post_id}
```

I came across the facebook graph api but failed any example I tried.

I'm using the **Graph API Explorer** facebook provided on https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ 
and tried getting the post object failed every time

```
GET/v2.8/{publisher_id}_{post_id}
```

leads to message "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '{publisher_id}_{post_id}' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"

when trying to reach the post just by using the post id I get "(#12) singular statuses API is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher"

Comment: For user posts, you first of all need `user_posts` permission from the user that wrote the post.

Comment: @CBroe how to get that permission? and also, what if this is my post ?

Comment: Like with all permissions - you ask for them during login. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/requesting-and-revoking // Doesn't matter if it is your post - that just means _you_ have to grant permission to your app then.